# Why does concatenating a list of string items generated from the name of a DataFrame column fail inside this function?

Tags: pandas, function, list-comprehension, f-string

I encountered a problem I can't explain when performing list concatenation inside vs. outside a function. Specifically, I tried to concatenate a list from a DataFrame column name inside a function and outside the function. Outside seems to work fine, but inside throws an error. See example below.

**Example**: Suppose I want to write a function that returns multiple lags of a column and assigns new names to the lagged variables based on the original column name. I could do something like this:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
rng = np.random.default_rng(22222222)

df = pd.DataFrame({'X':rng.random(10)})

print(df)
```

```
          X
0  0.279384
1  0.838032
2  0.298536
3  0.056188
4  0.532023
5  0.560038
6  0.127512
7  0.322774
8  0.813949
9  0.245242
```

Make the function:

```py
def lagger(column, lags): #Takes as input a DataFrame column in the form df[colname]
    lags = [column.shift(i) for i in range(1, lags+1)]

    df = pd.concat(lags, axis=1) #a DataFrame with a column for each lag.

    names = [f"{column.name}_L{i}" for i in range(1,lags+1)] #generate new names

    df.rename(names, axis='columns', inplace=True)

    return df
```

Testing the function, I get this error:

```py
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[27], line 1
----> 1 lagger(df['X'], 3)

Cell In[25], line 6
      2 lags = [column.shift(i) for i in range(1, lags+1)]
      4 df = pd.concat(lags, axis=1) #a DataFrame with a column for each lag.
----> 6 names = [f"{column.name}_L{i}" for i in range(1,lags+1)] #generate new names
      8 df.rename(names, axis='columns', inplace=True)
     10 return df

TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "int") to list
```

Something's going on with the list comprehension. Let's try doing a similar comprehension outside the function:

```py
[f"{df['X'].name}_L{i}" for i in range(1,4)]
```

```
['X_L1', 'X_L2', 'X_L3']
```

Works just fine!

So what's going on here? Why does this work outside the function but not inside?

To be clear, I've already found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48818213/make-multiple-shifted-lagged-columns-in-pandas) that clears up how to generate multiple lags. I'm not asking about that. I'm asking what's the difference between doing `[f"{column.name}_L{i}" for i in range(1,lags+1)]` inside the function versus `[f"{df['X'].name}_L{i}" for i in range(1,4)]` outside the function? Why does it fail inside the function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You overwrite your parameter `lags` with a list in your function. Thus `range(1, lags+1)` doesn't work anymore. Use another name. Also, your use of [`rename`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html) is incorrect, you should use [`set_axis`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_axis.html):

```
def lagger(column, lags): #Takes as input a DataFrame column in the form df[colname]
    l = [column.shift(i) for i in range(1, lags+1)]
    df = pd.concat(l, axis=1) #a DataFrame with a column for each lag.
    names = [f"{column.name}_L{i}" for i in range(1, lags+1)] #generate new names
    return df.set_axis(names, axis='columns')

lagger(df['X'], 3)
```